# Как обмениваться изображениями между React и Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, axios

Я разрабатываю фулл-стек интернет-магазин и мне нужно с реакта передавать изображение на мой Spring Rest Controller. Как мне это сделать? Я попытался сделать что-то типо того:

```
setFile(e.target.files && e.target.files[0])
```

Это файл из  `<input type="file"/>`

После этого я отправляю файл в put-методе

```
DishesService.addDish(dish, file)
```

```
static async addDish(dish: IDish, file: any) {
        try {
            await axios.post<IDish>('http://localhost:8080/dishes', dish)
                .then(response => {
                    this.updateDishImage(response.data.id, file)
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('произошла ошибка при добавлении блюда')
        }
    }

    static async updateDishImage(id: number | undefined, image: any) {
        try {
            await axios.put('http://localhost:8080/dishes/' + id, {}, {
                params: {
                    file: image
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Произошла ошибка при добавлении картинки к блюду')
        }
    }
```

И мой put-метод в контроллере Spring:

```
    @PutMapping("{dishId}")
    public ResponseEntity<DishEntity> updateDishImage(@PathVariable Long dishId, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        DishEntity updateDish = dishService.updateDishImage(file, dishId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(updateDish);
    }
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: получилось что или у вас остались вопросы?

Comment: если ответ решил вашу проблему, то см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) , если нет, то отпишитесь в комментариях под ответом

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я вижу, проблема в том, как вы с фронта подготавливаете и отправляете запрос.

```
await axios.put('http://localhost:8080/dishes/' + id, {}, {
    params: {
        file: image
    }
})
```

#### Content-Type

Начнем с того, что вы не указываете `Content-Type` запроса.
По умолчанию будет использоваться

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

При этом в контроллере Вы пытаетесь получить `MultipartFile file`, который подразумевает запрос типа  `multipart/form-data`

#### Передача данных

Вы передаете данные, через `params`(параметры запроса).
Это значит что параметры

```
{
    param1: "value1",
    param2: "value2",
    param3: "value3"
}
```

будут преобразованы в строку

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

и будут добавлены в адресную строку

```
http://localhost:8080/dishes/{id}?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

и в таком виде запрос уйдёт на сервер.

И это точно не наш вариант!

Для того, чтобы данные дошли до сервера их следует передавать в `data`

#### Что нужно делать

1. Указываем заголовок с корректным `Content-Type`
2. Собирваем данные и передаем их через `data`

```js
await axios({
  method: "put",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/dishes/' + id,
  // в data передаем объект с данными формы
  data: {  
         file: file,
         // ... при необходимости указываем другие поля формы
  },
  headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }, // указываем Content-Type
});
```