# Проблема с контроллером, который принимает base64 картинку в Spring

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, base64

Итак, я разрабатываю интернет-магазин и в нем есть возможность добавлять картинку. На React я кодирую картинку в base64 и передаю на сервер спринга в качестве строки.

```
export default class DishesService {
    static async addDish(dish: IDish, file: any) {
        try {
            await axios.post<IDish>('http://localhost:8080/dishes', dish)
                .then(response => {
                    this.updateDishImage(response.data.id, file)
                })
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('произошла ошибка при добавлении блюда')
        }
    }

    static async updateDishImage(id: number | undefined, image: any) {
        try {
            await axios.put('http://localhost:8080/dishes/' + id, {base64File: image})
        }
         catch (e) {
            console.log('Произошла ошибка при добавлении картинки к блюду')
        }
    }
}
```

Где file - это закодированная в base64 строка.

Теперь мой контроллер:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<DishEntity> saveDish(@RequestBody DishEntity dish) {
        DishEntity response = dishService.save(dish);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    @PutMapping("{dishId}")
    public ResponseEntity<DishEntity> updateDishImage(@PathVariable Long dishId, @RequestBody String base64File) {
        DishEntity response = dishService.updateDishImage(base64File, dishId);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public DishEntity updateDishImage(String base64File, Long dishId) {
        DishEntity dishById = findById(dishId);

        log.info("Updating dish image: {}", dishId);

        try{
            byte[] byteImage = Base64.decodeBase64(base64File);
            dishById.setImage(byteImage);
            log.info("byteImage: {}", byteImage);
            log.info("dish.getImage(): {}", dishById.getImage());
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new OperationFailedException("Base64 decoding failed!");
        }

        DishEntity updatedDish;
        try {
            updatedDish = dishRepository.save(dishById);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new OperationFailedException("Update dish image method failed!");
        }

        return updatedDish;
    }
```

Но до updateDishImage() так и не доходит, так как я получаю ошибку:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.internet_market_backend.entity.DishEntity> com.example.internet_market_backend.controller.DishController.updateDishImage(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)]
```

Кто сталкивался, подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: зачем в base64... вы пробовали применить ответ на свой же вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1447634/189027 ?.. не получилось?.. почему ничего в комментарии не написали если так?

Comment: запрос до контроллера доходит о чем и пишет ошибка

Comment: у вас опять уходит запрос не с тем `Content-Type`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB7Wh.png

Comment: при этом у меня с приложенным кодом все доходит до контроллера, только, как ни странно, в `base64File` попадает не код изображения, а весь `RequestBody` в виде JSON : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CB4o.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTqW2.png